# Karaf 3.0 is missing javax.validation requirement

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I get this missing requirement:

```
osgi.wiring.package =  javax.validation
```

in Karaf 3
I tried `bundle:install -s mvn:javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA` but it does not seem to install it correctly.

Any idea on how to resolve this missing requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Karaf 3.0.1 introduced a new hibernate-validator feature which is part of the enterprise repository, which is available by default:

```
> feature-list|grep hibernate-validator
hibernate-validator     | 5.0.3.Final   |       | enterprise-3.0.1    | Hibernate Validator support
> feature:info hibernate-validator
...
Feature contains followed bundles:
  mvn:javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final
  mvn:com.fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0
  mvn:javax.el/javax.el-api/2.2.4
  mvn:org.glassfish.web/javax.el/2.2.4
  mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.0.3.Final
  mvn:org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.1.4.GA
```

The hibernate-validator adds a few more validators on top of those specified in the bean validation API.

Answer (score 1):

Can you let me know the version of java that you are using, as well as the value of PROPERY JAVA_HOME.

Looks like you might be using Java 8. And I think it might not be supported at the present moment.

I had the same issue and switched to JDK1.7 and all the missing requirements errors for javax.* were resolved.

Answer (score 0):

you must wrap javax validation because it's not a valid bundle

the valid command :

install wrap:mvn:javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA

Answer (score 0):

Validation spec can be installed from various places. You can use apache bval together with geronimo specs:

- mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-validation_1.0_spec/1.1
- mvn:org.apache.bval/org.apache.bval.bundle/0.5

Bval have couple of dependencies:

- mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.1
- mvn:common-beanutils/common-beanutils/1.8.3

Geronimo specs is OSGi ready and works properly as long as you have only one spec implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If wrapping and hibernate-validator are not solved your problem you can try servicemix bundles

Apache ServiceMix :: Specs :: JSR 303 API 1.0.0

karaf side you should install bundle ..

```
>bundle:install mvn:org.apache.servicemix.specs/org.apache.servicemix.specs.jsr303-api-1.0.0/2.6.0
bundle 55
>start 55
>list
```

Also you should include package in project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.specs.jsr303-api-1.0.0</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Packages

```
javax.validation 
javax.validation.bootstrap    
javax.validation.constraints 
javax.validation.groups   
javax.validation.metadata 
javax.validation.spi   
org.apache.servicemix.specs.locator
```